# discord.js edit the message that send to user dm

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I want to edit the message that bot sent in an user's direct message, but I'm getting an error:

> message.author.edit is not a function

Here is my code:

```js
    if (message.content === "#مقابلة") {
        message.channel.send(eembed);   
        if (!(authorId in userApplications)) {
            userApplications[authorId] = { "step" : 1}
            
            
            message.author.send(embed1);
        }
  
    } else {
  
        if (message.channel.type === "dm" && authorId in userApplications) {
            let authorApplication = userApplications[authorId];
  
            if (authorApplication.step == 1 ) {
                authorApplication.answer1 = message.content;
                message.author.edit(embed2);
                authorApplication.step ++;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`TextChannel#send`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) method returns a promise with your standard [`<Message>`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object, you can call the [`Message.edit()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit) function on it like so:

```js
if (message.content === "#مقابلة") {
    message.channel.send(eembed);
    if (!(authorId in userApplications)) {
        userApplications[authorId] = {
            "step": 1
        }
        message.author.send(embed1).then((editMessage) => {

                if (message.channel.type === "dm" && authorId in userApplications) {
                    let authorApplication = userApplications[authorId];

                    if (authorApplication.step == 1) {
                        authorApplication.answer1 = message.content;
                        editMessage.edit(embed2);
                        authorApplication.step++;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if I replace my code with urs its and application bot it wont send answers of questions to the channel

Comment: You don't need to replace it, grab the essence of it what I sent was just an example , anyhow edited my answer with your code